# Search string per file once and print the file name

Tags: linux, grep, filenames

How may I use `grep` (or any other tool) to  search one string per file only once and also print that file name?

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -rFl "string" /path/
```

- `-r`: search recursively (not standard but pretty common)
- `-F`: fixed string search (as opposed to regexp pattern matching)
- `-l`: List name of the file containing `"string"`

You can also use:

```
find /path -type f -exec  grep -lF "string" {} +
```

If your `grep` doesn't support `-r`.

Comment: @Kusalananda, sorry, I just edited the recommendations at [that Q&A](/q/321697) in. Sourav, I'd suggest you read it.